# Piecewise highlighting in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, highlighting

I would like to do the following with `beamer`: All items of an `itemize` environment should be displayed in gray. The current item should be highlighted in black while all others remain grayed out, but visible (So for the example I would like to get three slides in the end: "Hallo" in black on slide 1, the rest in gray; "Welt" in black on the 2nd slide, all other items in gray, etc.). I just went through the manual, could not find any specific code to do so.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hallo
    \item Welt
    \item Foobar
  \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{%
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=gray,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black,bg=}
\usebeamercolor{normal text}
\begin{itemize}
\item \alert<+>{Hallo}
\item \alert<+>{Welt}
\item \alert<+>{Foobar}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That did the trick. It highlights only the current item and grays out all other. From the "how to present best" point of view Daniel's solution may however be more acceptable.

Answer (score 40):

The piecewise uncovering is described in §23 of the beamer user guide ("How to Uncover Things Piecewise"). To have the not (yet) uncovered items "dimmed" instead of invisible, you just need to combine this with a respective "transparency effect", discussed in §17.6   ("Transparency Effects").

The `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` can also be applied outside of a `frame` environment to have it's effect global.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame{
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Hallo
    \item Welt
    \item Foobar
  \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

The answer involves two things. You'll need to tell beamer which slides to highlight the text on, and that unhighlighted text should be *transparent*.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\frame{
\begin{itemize}
\item<1> Hallo
\item<2> Welt
\item<3> Foobar
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note, Daniel beat me to it, so send credit his way. I'll delete this soon.

Comment: Mark, I don't think that you should delete your answer. It already got some votes and shows a different syntax. Beamer's overlay stuff is just like that :-)

Comment: @Daniel: I'd actually forgotten about this answer! Busy time of year. ;)