# Beamer highlight only a part in an itemize frame

Tags: beamer, itemize, highlighting

How could I highlight only certain points in itemize environment. [The examples I found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/piecewise-highlighting-in-beamer-presentation) shows other parts also highlighted in the next slide. What I want is a single slide with one part highlighted and other blurred in the itemize environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  a TikZ `\node` and control the opacity using vopacity=`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\tikz\node[opacity=0.2,align=left,inner xsep=0pt]
{%
  \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
  \item Fourth item.
  \item Fifth item.
  \item Sixth item.}%
};
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want something like this. What I want is a "single slide" with say points 1,2,3 highlighted and say 4,5,6 blurred. This is to give an intuition that I am going to explain the following things in the coming slides...

Comment: @user3984 please see my updated answer. Something like that?

Comment: But my problem is i dont need to uncover 4,5,6.

Comment: @user3984 please explain exactly what you want. On slide 1 you see items 1,2 and 3 and items 4,5, and 6 are transparent, is that right? Then on the next slides what do you expect to see?

Comment: i only want to see slide one. no need to highlight 4,5,6 in next slides

Comment: @user3984 Ah, I understand now. Please see my updated answer. I hope it's something like that what you need.